# GridDB CM_LONG_IO Warning during Data Registration: Seeking Guidance on Resolution

Tags: nosql, griddb

While attempting data registration in GridDB, I encountered the CM_LONG_IO Warning with the following message:

```
Processing of the log file or data file may be taking longer than usual.
```

I've explored the documentation and found a recommendation that data registration and update may converge, possibly leading to data output if the load becomes high for a moment. The suggestion is to check with support if data is continuously output for an extended period.

I'm currently utilizing a WSL machine, and my GridDB version is "5.1.0-39692 CE."

Additionally, I would like to seek advice on what information I should provide to the GridDB support team to assist in resolving this issue. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has insights into potential causes, your guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Specifically, I'd like to know:

1. What information should I include when reaching out to GridDB support to help them address the CM_LONG_IO Warning during data registration?
2. Are there other scenarios or configurations that might lead to this Warning, and how can I mitigate them?